# Dialup Modem To Generate Musical Tones

Tags: audio, modem

Just brainstorming here but would it be possible to control the actual audio band signals emitted by a modem like an old US Robotics V.90 or similar? I'm guessing not without somehow rewriting the firmware of the modem itself but I'm asking anyway, karma be damned!

Comment: Probably could be done, but probably way more difficult and complicated than just building a tone generator to begin with.  It might be useful to scavenge the transformers that are used to actually safely connect the audio to the phone line, but I think that's about the only part that would make any sense.

Comment: Why? This sounds a bit like an XY problem, perhaps elaborate further?

Comment: Sure you could build a tone generator but there are a lot of these old modems laying around that have a small builtin bandwidth limiting speaker that give it that characteristic modem sound. So if they can be re-purposed by simply connecting them to a serial port and updating the firmware, that could be a fun project for some kid making electronic music. When interfaced with a little midi software it could be a cool sounding device.

Comment: Use your computer audio board.

Answer (score 2):

if the modem has voice capability you should be able to get telephone quality music out of it (300 to 3300Hz),  someone in superuser.stackexchange.com may be able to point you to usage details for voice mode.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably recreate [this type of touch tone music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_Ixg9G8DKM) using the AT commands to dial the right tones.  Other than that, the the data transmission frequencies wouldn't be that musical.

You could also sample the negotiation sequence sounds and general data transmission sounds and process them to make something musical.  There should be different tonal qualities depending on the baud rates.

Comment: It would not have to be limited to specific tones normally generated by the modem. Of course it would make sense to allow the diad type tones, it should be possible to generate any frequency in the usual range of 300 Hz - 4 kHz maybe. But again, the actual code generating the tones is builtin to the modem so all of this would depend on being able to re-write the firmware so that arbitrary tones could be generated in real time in reaction to commands (possibly AT commands if it makes things a lot easier).